# Equality of Two Real Analytic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both real analytic on an interval $(a,b)$, where $-\infty<a<b<\infty$.
Further suppose that
there exists an strictly increasing sequence of real values $\{x_{n}\}$ in $(a,b)$ such that

1. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=c\in (a,b)$, and
2. $f(x_{n})=g(x_{n})$ for all $n$.

Question: Do the conditions above ensure the existence of an interval $(a^{*},b^{*})\subseteq (a,b)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in (a^*,b^*)$?

Comment: How so? Pray tell.

Comment: Actually the equality holds on the full interval by the usual connectedness argument (take $A$ the set where $f-g$ and all its derivatives are zero; it is closed being given by a closed condition and open because by analyticity $f-g$ is the Taylor series at $c$ on a small interval around $c$, hence it is zero as the Taylor series is zero when $c \in A$; then $A$ nonempty, means full interval

Comment: @user8675309 Yes, it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you require $x$ to be strictly increasing; otherwise, we could have $x_n = c$ for all $n$ which tells us nothing except $f(c) = g(c)$.

Equivalently, consider an analytic $h : (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$ and also $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = c \in (a, b)$. We seek to show $h = 0$. To translate to this case, we could pick $h = f - g$.

It suffices to show that for all $n$, $h^{(n)}(c) = 0$. This is a fairly straightforward strong induction on $n$. For the $n = 0$ case, we use continuity to conclude that $h(c) = h(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} h(x_n) = 0$.

For the inductive step, suppose we have $h^{(0)}(c), h^{(1)}(c), \ldots, h^{(n)}(c) = 0$, and $h^{(n + 1)}(c) \neq 0$. Then there is some interval $(c - \epsilon, c)$ on which $h$ is nonzero. Take some $n$ such that $x_n \in (c - \epsilon, c)$. Then $h(x_n) = 0$. This is a contradiction.

Since $h^{(n)}(c) = 0$ for all $n$, we see that $h = 0$ on any connected set containing $c$ where $h$ is define, in particular on $(a, b)$. Therefore, $h = 0 = f - g$, so $f = g$.